# How can one create/ delete files in the /data/data dir using root in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, rooted-device

I'm working on a POC where I need to create and later on delete a file in the `/data/data` dir of a rooted device. I have tried to create a file in the standard way but it throws an `PERMISSION_DENNIED` exception as expected.
I know this is possible because the Root Explorer app can do it.

How can I programatically create/ delete a file via root?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Just run as root, then delete the file.  Its just like any other flavor of linux

Comment: Hi @GabeSechan! Thank you for your answer. I would like to be able to do that in code from my app. Any idea how might one achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @GabeSechan comment I was able to achieve this using this commands.

Create new file:

```
final String[] sCommand = {"su", "-c", "touch /data/..."};
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sCommand);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Issue occurred while creating new file " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And delete file:

```
final String[] sCommand = {"su", "-c", "rm /data/..."};
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sCommand);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Issue occurred while deleting " + e.getMessage());
}
```